# Convert XML-file to a sorted

Tags: c#, xml

I trying to write a program that converts a XML file to a sorted ordered-by-date
The XML file looks like this:

```
    <Root>
         <Orders>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-07-14T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>4.42</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-07-31T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-08-28T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-08-05T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>116.53</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-09-25T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-10-23T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-09-30T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
        <Freight>76.13</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1998-01-06T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1998-02-03T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1998-02-04T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>719.78</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1998-04-07T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1998-05-05T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1998-04-15T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>25.19</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1998-04-22T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1998-05-20T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo>
        <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
        <Freight>18.84</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
</Orders>
    </Root>
```

I want it to be sorted by **OrderDate** But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: There's no direct way to sort file data. You can read the file, create object of the XML (deserialize etc.), sort that object and write back to file if you want.

Comment: Yes I want that. How do I do it?

Comment: What is your goal? Having an xml file with entries sorted by *OrderDate* or a program for reading and writing xml files? You could use XSL for sorting if you just want that XML file being sorted (but I'm not sure if the main purpose of XML is to be sorted). Of you want to write a program my first approach would be to create some objects representing the ORDERs, CUSTOMERs etc., reading the file and creating the objects, storing them in a list of, order that list and persist the list as an XML file again.

Comment: From the comments and answer, you get some idea how to go about that. But, rather than ordering the XML file, in most cases, better idea would be to order the data from XML where you'll be using that.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc);//xmlDoc = your xml file or input stream
IList<XElement> records = xDoc.Root.Elements("Order").OrderBy(x => x.Element("OrderDate").Value).ToList();
```

This is a list of all the Order records ordered by OrderDate

If you want it in a file, recreate the XML file using 'records' as your data source

Comment: `x.Element("OrderDate").Value` will be string, try casting that to `DateTime`.

Comment: Replace .Value with .ToShortDateString() maybe?

Haven't done too much work with this...

Comment: or append: Value.ToShortDateString()

Comment: I'm really not sure which `ToDateTime()` you are talking about, `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()` should work.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the info. Will test it a bit later :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Linq XML.  I think it is easier to add to a new XML element than to sort original

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<Root>" +
                    "<Orders>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-07-14T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>4.42</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-07-31T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-08-28T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-08-05T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>116.53</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-09-25T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-10-23T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-09-30T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>3</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>76.13</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-01-06T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-02-03T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1998-02-04T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>719.78</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-04-07T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-05-05T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1998-04-15T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>25.19</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-04-22T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-05-20T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo>" +
                            "<ShipVia>3</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>18.84</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                    "</Orders>" +
                "</Root>";

            XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var sortedOrder = root.Descendants("Order").Select(x => new
            {
                order = x,
                orderDate = (DateTime)x.Element("OrderDate")
            }).OrderBy(y => y.orderDate).ToList();

            XElement sortedXml = new XElement("Root", new XElement("Orders"));
            XElement orders = sortedXml.Descendants("Orders").FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (var ordered in sortedOrder)
            {
                orders.Add(ordered.order);
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```